# awk regex while loop

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to write a loop, using regex, can someone help me please.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do

done
```

Comment: Why are you doing the `while read line`? What input are you expecting from the user?

Comment: seems also that "bin/bash" should be "/bin/bash"

Comment: Is it just me or is there a (single) quote missing in the second awk? You could add `if [ "$line" = "q" ] ; then exit; fi` to your loop.

Comment: Why do you need the loop at all? Your awk prints are doing the job just fine as you want.

Comment: Hi, simply run the following test on the Linux terminal. awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $7 == "/bin/bash" {print $1}' /etc/passwd
   awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $7 != "/bin/bash" {print $1"*"} /etc/passwd
I am sure your script should be only the two awk commands. At least you won't fall into the infinite loop. Please excuse me for not having quite formatted the awk commands, since you have them correctly, should be OK

Answer (score 2):

one `awk` script should do, no `while` loops required.

```
$ awk -F: '$3>=1000{print $1 (($7=="/bin/bash")?"":"*")}' /etc/passwd
```